# Ruby on Rails - Fixtures populate sqlite3 database with wrong utf-8 encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, fixture

Seeding the sqlite3 database with Fixtures did work with config1 but with config2 utf-8 support fails.

config1: Ubuntu 11.04, ruby 1.9.2p136, Rails 3.0.3, "development" environment

config2: OS X Lion, ruby 1.9.2p290, Rails 3.0.3, "development" environment

When having a yml file like

```
001: 
  id: 1
  name: "\xC3\xBC"
```

I use it to populate the database with

```
Fixtures.create_fixtures(...)
```

in seed.rb

Afterwards the database shout have an entry with id 1 and name "ü". That would be correct.
That worked with config1. With config2 I alway have an entry with name "Ã¼". utf-8 encoding seems to fail.

I already turned on UTF-8 everywhere in the rails project:

```
encoding: utf-8
```

in database.yml

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

in seeds.rb

```
Encoding.default_external = "UTF-8"
Encoding.default_internal = "UTF-8"
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

in config/environments/development.rb

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that these two systems have different endianness?

From the SQLite3 release notes:

> Support for UTF-8 and UTF-16
>
> The new API for SQLite 3.0 contains routines that accept text as both
>   UTF-8 and UTF-16 in the native byte order of the host machine. Each
>   database file manages text as either UTF-8, UTF-16BE (big-endian), or
>   UTF-16LE (little-endian).

You can check here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_and_operating_systems_on_architectures